# tensorflow - memory leak?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, tensorflow

I'm running tensorflow 0.10.0rc0 on OSX 10.9.5 Mavericks.

There are approximately 25k training examples, 250 features (x), 15 classes (y_) and the predict (y) is a single-hidden-layer NN perceptron.

The following snippet of a simple training loop seems to have a massive memory leak (of order 10s of GBs over =~ 200 iterations - brings down my MBP :( ) :

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Initialize placeholders and variables etc...
...

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y,y_))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lrate).minimize(cost)    

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(niter):
    # Train
    _,c=sess.run([train_step,cost])
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1),tf.argmax(y_,1))
    sess.run(correct_prediction)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))
    print sess.run(accuracy)

    # EDIT: Calculate test error
    ytest=sess.run(y[itrain:itrain+itest,:])
    ytest_=sess.run(y_[itrain:itrain+itest,:])
    test_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(ytest,1), tf.argmax(ytest_,1))
    test_accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(test_prediction,tf.float32))
    print sess.run(test_accuracy)

sess.close()
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong, or is this per chance a bug? Thanks!

PS: If this is fixed in a later tensorflow build, note that bazel requires Yosemite or higher, so I can't generate my own .whl file (AFAIK) from source; is a nightly whl available? I would rather not be forced into an OS upgrade right now.

Comment: Edit: I added the test accuracy calculation; I am not sure how to remove this from the loop, since y needs to be evalulated after the training step

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Its unnecessary to run `sess.run(correct_prediction)` -- it's a tensorflow graph variable on which the `accuracy` variable is dependant. This implies that it will be evaluated during the call to `sess.run(accuracy)` in any case.
2. You're probably modifying your graph by creating new `correct_prediction` and `accuracy` variables on each iteration. This is also unnecessary -- they can be moved outside the loop and simply evaluated each time with calls to `sess.run`. So your inner loop will be something like

```
for i in range(niter):
    # Train
    _, c = sess.run([train_step, cost])
    print sess.run(accuracy)
```

Comment: Thanks @Simon that helps massively - the RAM usage is much much more stable. I suspect the remaining "leakage" is coming from a second test-set accuracy evaluation within the loop. Now to fix it....